# Removing an array with a particular match

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to remove the array where `name="All"` in `$scope.selectedAccounts`, but with what I am doing at the moment, `$scope.selectedAccounts` returns empty.

What am I doing wrong?

***controller.js***

```
function AccountController($scope, DummyAccountService) {
    // this works, but returns everything... I need it for something else
    $scope.accounts = DummyAccountService.dummyAccounts; 

    // this doesn't return anything
    $scope.selectedAccounts = function() {
        var selectedAccountsArray = [];
        for(i=0; i < $scope.accounts.length; i++) {
            var account = $scope.accounts[i];
            if($scope.accounts.name != "All") {
                selectedAccountsArray.push(account);
            }
        }
        return selectedAccountsArray;
    }
}
```

***services.js***

```
function DummyAccount(id, profileId, name, tag, icon, positive, negative, neutral, currentRating) {
    this.id = id;
    this.profileId = profileId;
    this.name = name;
    this.tag = tag;
    this.icon = icon;
    this.positive = positive;
    this.negative = negative;
    this.neutral = neutral;
    this.currentRating = currentRating;
}

function DummyAccountService() {
    this.dummyAccounts = [
        new DummyAccount(1, 1, 'Facebook', 'Remy Danton', 'ion-social-facebook', 61, 12, 27, "C"),
        new DummyAccount(2, 1, 'Twitter', '@remydanton', 'ion-social-twitter', 75, 12, 13, "B"),
        new DummyAccount(3, 1, 'Web Agent', 'Remy Danton', 'ion-earth', 87, 10, 3, "A"),
        new DummyAccount(4, 1, 'All', 'Remy Danton', 'ion-person', 64, 11, 25, "B")
    ]
}
```

**UPDATE:** I've made all the suggested changes below but `selectedAccounts` still returns empty. Not sure what is happening... I've pasted the entirety of my code here: http://pastebin.com/JtM8nq3X.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing index value of array or not comparing local account variable. Created Plunkar here https://plnkr.co/edit/eByE5q4qApjjf8rUtEPz?p=preview

Change this

```
for(i=0; i < $scope.accounts.length; i++) {
        var account = $scope.accounts[i];
        if($scope.accounts.name != "All") {
            selectedAccountsArray.push(account);
        }
    }
```

to

```
for(i=0; i < $scope.accounts.length; i++) {
        var account = $scope.accounts[i];
        if(account.name != "All") {
            selectedAccountsArray.push(account);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please change **ng-repeat="account in selectedAccounts"** to **ng-repeat="account in selectedAccounts()"**.

Comment: Welcome ..! Happy to hear ...!

Answer (score 1):

Change `if($scope.accounts.name != "All") {` to `if(account.name != "All") {`.  `$scope.accounts` doesn't have a `name` field, so that if is never going to push `account`.

Comment: Please check updated question. For some reason, `selectedAccounts` is still returning as empty even despite the changes.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
if($scope.accounts.name != "All") {
      selectedAccountsArray.push(account);
}
```

to

```
if($scope.accounts[i].name !== "All") {
      selectedAccountsArray.push(account);
}
```

-- I think you want $scope.selectedAccounts to be the new array but you have it set to a function - you must execute the function so $scope.selectedAccounts is populated with the results you want

```
$scope.selectedAccounts = (function() {
    var selectedAccountsArray = [];
    for(i=0; i < $scope.accounts.length; i++) {
        var account = $scope.accounts[i];
        if($scope.accounts.name != "All") {
            selectedAccountsArray.push(account);
        }
    }
    return selectedAccountsArray;
})();
```

just wrap it up in an IIFE

Comment: Please check updated question. For some reason, `selectedAccounts` is still returning as empty even despite the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Others have already pointed out the syntax mistake; FWIW here's a cleaner way to return everything except the account whose `name` is `All`:

```
$scope.selectedAccounts = function ()
{
    return $scope.accounts.filter(function (acc)
    {
        return acc.name != "All";
    });
}
```

Comment: Please check updated question. For some reason, `selectedAccounts` is still returning as empty even despite the changes.